# PandaSeq install error: ltld required, install libtool library

Tags: compiling

I'm trying to install [PandaSeq](https://github.com/neufeld/pandaseq) as a non-administrator on a Red Hat server but the compiler is returning the following error:

```
...
checking ltdl.h usability... no
checking ltdl.h presence... no
checking for ltdl.h... no
configure: error: *** ltld required, install libtool library.
```

So I verified all the dependencies are installed:

```
whereis libtool : /usr/bin/libtool /usr/share/libtool
whereis zlib : /usr/include/zlib.h /usr/local/zlib /usr/share/man/man3/zlib.3.gz
whereis libbz2 : /usr/lib64/libbz2.so
whereis bzip2 : /usr/bin/bzip2 /usr/local/bzip2 /usr/share/man/man1/bzip2.1.gz
```

The compiler commands I'm using are:

```
git clone http://github.com/neufeld/pandaseq.git/
cd pandaseq
./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/my/dir
```

Any ideas how to make the compiler see `libtool` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably [libltdl](https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html) is distributed as a separate development package on your distribution

Answer (score 0):

In the end, our server administrator installed the following packages which resulted in a successful installation of PANDAseq:

```
libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
libtool-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
libtool-ltdl-devel-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64
```

The PANDA is happy now :)